# How would I go about creating a mod_rewrite that redirects to launch.php?i=/the/url/that/they/want?

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite

So if the user types **mydomain.com/dashboard**, the document the server actually sends them is **/launch.php?i=/dashboard**.

The one caveat is that I would like to leave requests for

- /flags
- /people
- /posters
- /css
- /icons
- /images
- /libraries
- /patterns

alone, and they should request the actual folder.

How would I create such a mod_rewrite?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the .htaccess file for the [CakePHP](http://www.cakephp.org) Framework.

Please replace the index.php and ?url= to fit your needs.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

The "!-d" tells Apache to follow existing folders and "!-f" to follow existing files.

Everything else is channelled through index.php

As suggested in a comment, you have to be aware that if it's not working it could be because mod_rewrite is not enabled and you'll not get an error stating that fact, you'll probably only have a HTTP 404.

Comment: <IfModule > is bad practice. Your application will silently fail if you don't have mod_rewrite enabled isntead of throwing a big bad error that would make you fix it immediately.